# How to create an alias for a named SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, localhost, alias

On my developer computer I have an SQL Server instance named *developer_2005*. In the resource setting files of a C# application we are creating, the instance name is set to *foobar* (not really, but just as an example). So when I run the application (in debug or realease) it tries to connect to an SQL Server on localhost, named *foobar*.

I am wondering if it is possible to create an alias or something like that, so that the application actually finds an SQL Server on localhost named *foobar*, but it is actually connecting to the instance named *developer_2005*.

The connection string in the config file of the application is *Data Source=localhost\foobar;Initial Catalog=barfoo;Integrated Security=True* with provider name *System.Data.SqlClient*. If I change *localhost\foobar* to *localhost\developer_2005* then the application can connect like it should. How can I create an alias so that I won't have to change the string in the file?

*I tried, in SQL Server Management Studio, to create a Server Registration with registered server name "localhost\developer", but this didn't seem to do any good. Not even sure what that really did... But then I discovered SQL Server Configuration Manager\SQL Native Client COnfiguration\Aliases. And I kind of assume this is where the solution lies. But I can't quite figure out how to add a new one... When creating a new one, I have to provide Alias Name, Port No, Protocol and Server, and I don't really have a clue what to put in either of them.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alias name: foobar (the name you would like to use)

Server name: the actual name of your computer or the IP address (not localhost or 127.0.0.1)

Protocol: TCP/IP

Port: the default one (1433)

Make sure TCP/IP protocoll is enabled (disabled by default)

Change your connection string to use your new alias  (Data Source=foobar)

Comment: The server name, *localhost*, is correct. It is the named instance name I need to create an alias for.

Comment: Then you should use *localhost\instancename* as the server name.

Comment: what about the alias name? Should I use *localhost\developer_2005* as server name and *localhost\foobar* as alias? Will that work?

Comment: I checked better... looks like you actually *can* do that. At least in SQL server 2008 (don't know if it will work in 2005).

Comment: I edited my answer, try that.

Comment: Interesting. Will try that.

Comment: Totally worked :D

Comment: Because this answer came with the "change your connection string to use your new alias" step, which solved it for me. An alias name of *localhost\foobar* didn't work here. Probably because of SQL Server 2005. Upvoted you both though. If you add info about this in your answer I could move the Accepted answer maybe. Cause yours is cleaner set up more informational.

Comment: That's ok, I thought it actually worked *without* changing the connection string, but that's not your case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, what you need to do is defining a new alias in the Native Client configuration.

- Alias name: the alias you want to create
- Server name: the actual server name
- Protocol: TCP/IP
- Port: the default one (1433)

Try this:

- Alias name: localhost\foobar
- Server name: localhost\developer_2005
- Protocol: TCP/IP
- Port: 1433

Comment: And that is where I am. But what do I put in those fields? I don't quite get it...

Comment: The connection string in the config file is *Data Source=localhost\foobar;Initial Catalog=barfoo;Integrated Security=True* with provider name *System.Data.SqlClient*. For it to connect correctly I must change *localhost\foobar* to *localhost\developer_2005*. How can I create an alias so that I don't have to do that?

Comment: This can't be done; your connection string is looking for a **named instance** called *foobar*, aliases can only be used as top-level names, not as they were named instances themselves.

Comment: So there is no way of solving this, other than changing the connection string in the application?

Comment: I checked better... looks like you actually can do that. At least in SQL server 2008 (don't know if it will work in 2005).

Comment: Aha. Maybe that is why it doesn't work here then.

Comment: If your alias is pointing to a named instance, you need to take into account TCP ports; have a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265808.

Comment: Add this in case anyone else comes along and find the solution here doesn't work. Turns out I had to clear the Port setting from the alias to get this to work for me.

Comment: me too.  and I would also add that my options included a node for 32-bit as well as 64 bit.  It was the 32-bit that I had to configure for SQL 2008 R2 Express